# Dynamic pages in Next.js won't link back to normal pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a web site created with next.js, it has a section which is dynamic routing stored in a folder `pages/artists/[slug].js` which is great, I have to whole dynamic routing working perfectly fine.

The issue comes when I click in the navbar to go back to a standard pages i.e. Home, About or Contact.

Where is should link to `/contact` or `/about` it ends up linking to `/artists/contact` or `/artists/about`

How should I fix this issue? I can't seem to find anything online regarding this issue.

Thank you

Edit: Code for nav component

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import config from '../../config'
export default function Menu() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);
  const menuToggle = () => {
    setMenu(!menu),
      [menu, setMenu]

  }
  return (
    <>
      <a id="menubtn" onClick={menuToggle}>
        <svg width="40" height="40">
          <rect width="40" height="3" x="0" y="12"/>
          <rect width="40" height="3" x="0" y="24"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <nav id="menu">
        <a id="close" onClick={menuToggle}>&times;</a>
        <ul>
          {config.navigation.map((link) => (
            <li key={link}>
              <Link href={link}>
                <a onClick={menuToggle}>{link.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + link.slice(1)}</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
)}
```

Answer (score 3):

I took a closer look at the code after sending it and noticed that the `<Link>` href's looked like this

```
<Link href={link}>
  <a onClick={menuToggle}>  {link.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + link.slice(1)}</a>
</Link>
```

The issue there being that the router takes the browser to `about` not `/about` which obviously causes issues on the dynamic pages.

I updated the code to this which fixed it

```
<Link href={`/${link}`}>
  <a onClick={menuToggle}>{link.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + link.slice(1)}</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some code would help a lot to identify the issue. All i could say right now is double check your Link tags. Make sure you're importing the next/link package.

[Docs reference next/link - Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

Comment: Where would you like to see code from?

The dynamic routed page? 

The header nav component?

Comment: I believe the nav component may be causing the issue but i can't be certain. Please let me take a look at it and i'll gladly let you know if i see anything odd. 
Do you also need a nav reference to the dynamic route?

Comment: I have added the nav code component. Also no I do not, they are navigated to via an `artists` page which is separate from the navbar

Comment: That's great, i think i found a new lead.  Perhaps the map function is mixing up the link tags. 
Could you show me what's in "import config from '../../config'"? I presume it would be helpful to take a look specifically at the config.navigation section.

Comment: It's okay @Azpil the config files are fine, it was a lack of / in the href's see my answer below